# How to model a single-pole, triple-throw switch in PSpice?

Tags: switches, pspice, transient, analog-switch

I would like to model the following circuit in PSpice:

[image]

It is a single-pole, triple-throw switch implementation.
I have tried to model it using Sbreak like below, however, I get a floating node error.
How can I model this without running in mto this issue?

[image]

Comment: Can you connect the floating node at S3 to a known voltage through a massive (i.e. 1 GΩ) resistor? I don't know pspice but that's usually what's needed in other simulators.

Comment: The Roff for these Sbreaks is 10 Mohms. What ends up happening is that 5V and 0V get connected in series with two 10Mohm resistors and Vout becomes 2.5V.

Comment: I'd be surprised to see a "floating node" error in that case. The only disconnected node I see is on S3.